# Can I console.log into Selenium driver?

Tags: python, selenium, logging, console, console.log

I'd like to know if it's possible to write into the console of an opened page in selenium webdriver, for example, like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
driver.console.log("something")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   driver.execute_script("console.log('something')")
```

Use driver.execute_script to execute javascript on browser console

Comment: That's what I was looking for and works perfectly, thank you!